# WPF binding HorizontalAlignment to TextAlignment

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBoxItem` whose `HorizontalAlignment` property is changed by an Converter, according to the width of the `Window`. I have a `TextBlock` inside this `ListBoxItem` whose `TextAlignment` property is binded to the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `ListBoxItem`.

The `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `ListBoxItem` is changing correctly; however, the text alignment of the `TextBlock` remains unchanged. Where is the error?

Here is the code of the binding (I didn't show the Converter of the `ListBoxItem` because it is working correctly (according to the `Window width`, it changes from `Left` to `Center`)):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" 
                   TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=HorizontalAlignment}"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Man, you are a detective! I did an experiment that worked, but I can't explain why. I used a MultiBinding instead of a Binding, passing AcualWidth property, which actually is not used by the Converter. Now the TextAlignment is working and is updated when ListBoxItem's HorizontalAlignment changes. I used the following code:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text">
    <TextBlock.TextAlignment>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HorizontalToTextAlignmentConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            <Binding Path="HorizontalAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.TextAlignment>
</TextBlock>
```

Could you explain why it worked with MultiBind rather than a simple Binding? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: first of all `TextAlignment` & `HorizontalAlignment` are two different enums so may not be fully compatible with each other. but you may give a try by adding `Mode=TwoWay` in the binding.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I've tried this but it did not work. Is there any way to convert from HorizontalAligment to TextAlignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two different enumerations:

**TextAlignment Enumeration:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx

**HorizontalAlignment Enumeration:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx

While `TextAlignment` contains `Center`, `Justify`, `Left` and `Right`, `HorizontalAlignment` contains `Center`, `Left`, `Right` and `Stretch`.  So, as you see, they are not the same.

Create a converter if you want to use one based on the other.

Here's a very basic converter (adjust to your liking):

```
public class HorizontalToTextAlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextAlignment textAlignment;

        // All I'm doing here is simply getting the integer value of the Enumeration.
        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 0:
                // Left to Left
                textAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
                break;
            case 1:
                // Center to Center
                textAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Right to Right
                textAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
                break;
            default:
                // Stretch to Justify
                textAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;
                break;
        }

        return textAlignment;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment;

        // All I'm doing here is simply getting the integer value of the Enumeration.
        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 0:
                // Left to Left
                horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                break;
            case 1:
                // Right to Right
                horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Center to Center
                horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                break;
            default:
                // Justify to Stretch
                horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                break;
        }

        return horizontalAlignment;
    }
}
```

`XAML` test code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HorizontalToTextAlignmentConverter x:Key="h2tAlignmentConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" 
                       TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=HorizontalAlignment, Converter={StaticResource h2tAlignmentConverter}}"
                       Width="400"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

`MSDN` order of these numerations was a bit off, so I just went into the code to figure them out.  Here's their code for your reference:

```
public enum TextAlignment
{
    Left = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Center = 2,
    Justify = 3,
}

public enum HorizontalAlignment
{
    Left = 0,
    Center = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Stretch = 3,
}
```

**EDIT:**

I thought a bit about your last comment, and I think you may not be seeing changes to the text alignment due to the `TextBlock` itself not aligning within the `ListBoxItem` parent.  So, as one of the possible scenarios, if `ListBoxItem` is bigger than `TextBlock`, you won't see the proper changes.  You can accomplish synchronization of their alignments by binding `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `ListBoxItem` to its own `HorizontalAlignment`.

Here's `XAML`:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red"
                     Width="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HorizontalAlignment}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" Background="Green" Foreground="White"
                       TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=HorizontalAlignment, Converter={StaticResource h2tAlignmentConverter}}"
                       Width="300"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Here's a visual representation of the different alignments. `ListBoxItem` is `Red`, `TextBlock` is `Green` and `ListBox` occupies the entire `Grid` & `Window`.

`Left` alignment:

[image]

`Right` alignment:

[image]

`Center` alignment:

[image]

`Stretch` alignment (text is `Justified`):

[image]

The best part is that `HorizontalContentAlignment` is simply a `HorizontalAlignment`, so no conversion is needed.

Comment: BK, many thanks for the help! Only the first and second options of the first switch were reversed. But the property in the TextBlock is still not being updated. It starts correctly (TextBlock TextAlignment starts justified as the ListBoxItem starts Streched), but, when ListBoxItem changes to Center, TextAlignment does not change). I do not know what is happening.

Comment: @user3952846 Yeah, I fixed the code, refer to the latest version.  `MSDN` was off on their order.  I've tested and this works without any issues (make sure that you use my latest Converter code).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest code. As I said, it's doing the conversion correctly. Just is not updating when the ListBoxItem changes alignment. Many thanks for the great help, but I have to go for a while (it's already 1:30 in the morning and I go to sleep). I will continue tomorrow. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user3952846 I think I figured out the issue.  It has to do with the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ListBoxItem` See my edit for an easy fix.

Comment: BK, I did some changes that worked. Take a look at the last edition in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @user3952846 It has to do with you matching their width.  Color them like I did and you'll see the difference between the two codes.  That's why I did the binding on `HorizontalContentAlignment`, so that the alignments match no matter the width.  Remember to mark it as the answer if it helped you.