# Wpf Binding vs MultiBinding update

Tags: wpf

I had an issue that has been resolved.

[WPF binding HorizontalAlignment to TextAlignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944551/wpf-binding-horizontalalignment-to-textalignment)

I have a ListBoxItem whose HorizontalAlignment property is changed by a Converter, according to the width of the Window. I have a TextBlock inside this ListBoxItem whose TextAlignment property is binded to the HorizontalAlignment property of the ListBoxItem.

First, I used a Simple Binding, that didn't work (the HorizontalAlignment of the ListBoxIten changed, but the TextAlignment was not updated). Here is the code:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" 
               TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=HorizontalAlignment}"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

After,  I used a MultiBinding instead of a Binding, passing AcualWidth property, which actually is not used by the Converter. Now the TextAlignment is updated when ListBoxItem's HorizontalAlignment changes. I used the following code:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text">
    <TextBlock.TextAlignment>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HorizontalToTextAlignmentConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            <Binding Path="HorizontalAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.TextAlignment>
</TextBlock>
```

The Converter itself is the same, it just has one more variable (ActualWidth of the Window) that is not used. So, my question is: Why the TextAlignment was update only with a MultiBinding?

Comment: Could it be a side effect in the order of how two values are calculated? Passing in ActualWidth forces it to finish the measure step, and calculate the result before it is passed to the converter, even though it doesn't use it. The measure step can take several iterations, and really seems to mess up sometimes, and especially with alignment.

Comment: Maybe you're right, Dean. However, I'd like to make sure, because I don't like the idea of having to pass a parameter that is not used. Thanks for the answer.