# WPF/xaml How to Bind to HorizontalAlignment

Tags: wpf, binding

To what would I bind to, to manipulate the HorizontalAlignment? Passing a simple string doesn't seem to work, but I can't find an example of what does.

```
private string _CategoryHorizontalAlignment;
public string CategoryHorizontalAlignment
    {
        get { return _CategoryHorizontalAlignment; }
        set
        {
            _CategoryHorizontalAlignment = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryHorizontalAlignment");
        }
    }

...
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
       <Border x:Name="_brdMain" 
               BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
               BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
               CornerRadius="7,7,7,7" Padding="{Binding CategoryPadding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
           <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="{Binding CategoryHorizontalAlignment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
       </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx). The property's type is [HorizontalAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx), not string. Also note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your Bindings is pointless. It has no effect here.

Comment: When doing data-binding with a non compatible property (in term of type) and if needed, you can also consider using converters (http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomValueConverter.aspx)

Comment: Looking here may also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944551/wpf-binding-horizontalalignment-to-textalignment

Comment: Thanks.  HorizontalAlignment property was what I was missing.